# Invalid Conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*'

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, arduino

I am having a small problem with an Arduino program I am trying to write to read a command sent from Processing over a serial connection. Processing is supposed to send either a 'H' or an 'L' over the serial connection to the Arduino. This value is stored as a char in my program but when I try to do Serial.write("Value: %c",val) I get a "Invalid Conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*'" error. If someone can help me solve this problem that would be great. I really need to figure out what this value is so I can re-write my program. Thanks!

Code is provided below:

```
char val; // variable to receive data from the serial port

int ledpin = 8; // LED connected to pin 48 (on-board LED)

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);  // pin 48 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  Serial.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 9600bps
}
void loop() {

  while (Serial.available()>0){

  val=Serial.read();
  }
  //Serial.write("Value: %c",(char)val);

  if( val == 'H' )               // if 'H' was received
  {
Serial.write("Setting Value to High \n");
digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);  // turn ON the LED
  } else { 
Serial.write("Setting Value to Low \n");
digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);   // otherwise turn it OFF
  }
    Serial.flush();
        delay(100);                    // wait 100ms for next reading
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Serial.write`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) is not `printf` - it doesn't take a format string as an argument. Have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use in stead of serial.write: Serial.print or Serial.println(witch prints at the end of the string \r\n)